# Regex for validating string for space at the beginning and end

Tags: regex

I am writing regex expression will accept the string those are not starting or ending with spaces. But the spaces in between are allowed.
My string contains only alphanumeric character. I have written regex for checking alphanumeric string with specific  length as 10 allowing spaces.

`[A-Za-z0-9\s]{10}`.

This allows spaces at begining and end also. I have tried with `\S` to ommit space at the begining. But didn't work. Any suggestion on this regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9](?!.*?\s$)[A-Za-z0-9\s]{0,9}$
```

This will enforce 1st and last character to be alphanumeric while allowing space in the middle 8 characters.